# Any readymade project/Framework using Php smarty for big application

Tags: php, frameworks, smarty, projects-and-solutions

I am just new in php smarty Framework. and i am just looking for some ready-made sample base project using php smarty which help to speed up my development like i easy understand project structure (project solution ) for big project , collection for classes for database,..etc

I am not able how to do start project using php smarty, their is not documentation available to how to create project using smarty .

i we just want to classes , AJAX , themes ..etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having used Smarty in the past it has several disadvantages in real-world applications. First, it's getting kinda slow and pollutes everything with caches. Also it has a large footprint. Finally It puts lots of creepy-code into templates which our designer simply can't figure out. Back when we were using Dreamweaver (probably in 2000), smarty tags were often messed up during design.

Some frameworks let you use any template engine. Others have their built-in one. The way I see it - the simpler template engine is, the better.

For the [PHP UI Framework](http://agiletoolkit.org/) which I started, I wanted to have something simple enough with only the concept of "tag" and "region". The rest is done by the PHP code, it decides which regions to use, and how to insert them into tags.

Your main template has `<?$Content?>` region, which get's populated with page's template. There you insert views such as forms, grids, etc and each of those would have their own template too.

Simple template engine also gave big advantage of simplifying AJAX integration into [Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/) and allowed to do it completely transparent. Ability to re-define certain templates locally (by replacing global ones) gives great support for theming and white-labeling.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after, but the [Open Journal Systems](http://pkp.sfu.ca/?q=ojs) and [Open Conference Systems](http://pkp.sfu.ca/?q=ocs) from the [Public Knowledge Project](http://pkp.sfu.ca/) are large projects which use Smarty.  Perhaps you can start there?

Answer (score 1):

[Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) has support for Smarty, here's a [tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/120) on integrating Smarty in Zend.